# pie chart with angled/horizontal labels in dc.js

Tags: pie-chart, dc.js

I need to match the designs to have the label extruding out with a horizontal line attached to the slice ticks. Is this possible?

[image: pie chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is support for lines to slice labels as of dc.js 2.0 beta 20.

It's called `drawPaths`:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.pieChart+drawPaths

It could be improved, as noted [in the PR](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/986#issuecomment-152697166), but it's a start.